# Como validar los StandarButtons de un QMessageBox usando una enumeración

Tags: python, pyqt5

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto y estoy utilizando una enumeración para validar el tipo de botón que es accionado y que devuelva un valor entero dependiendo del mismo:

```
class code(Enum):
    QMessageBox.Ok = 1
    QMessageBox.Cancel = 2
```

Pero el problema que tengo es que al momento de obtener el valor desde la enumeración obtengo el siguiente error:

> ValueError: 1024 is not a valid code

¿Cómo puedo comprobar esos valores usando la enumeración con las variantes de los botones de `QMessageBox`?

**Código Completo**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QMessageBox
from enum import Enum

class code(Enum):
    QMessageBox.Ok = 1
    QMessageBox.Cancel = 2

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.setWindowTitle("error")
        msg.setText("error")

        msg_exec = msg.exec()

        print(code(msg_exec).value)


app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Hice una autorespuesta para poder hablar de manera más general de este escenario. Espero que te sirva: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/601848/c%C3%B3mo-convierto-un-enum-de-pyqt-en-uno-de-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hace falta que crees ese Enum, ya lo tienes de QMessageBox, solo úsalos

En msg_exe tienes el resultado de QmessageBox, solo tienes que verificar que botón fué clickeado con:

```
   if msg_exec == QMessageBox.Ok:
      print('Ok clicked')
   elif msg_exec == QMessageBox.Cancel:
      print('Cancel clicked')
```

Comment: claro se que puedo hacerlo de esa manera pero mi intención es usar la enumeración para probar otros métodos