# ¿Cómo convierto un enum de PyQt en uno de Python?

Tags: python, pyqt, enum, pyside

En pyqt y pyside, existen los enums, pero estos no tienen ciertas caracteristicas que me vendrían bien y que si están en el modulo [enum](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/enum.html). ¿Hay alguna manera de convertir los enum originales en enums de enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Estrategia base

Cada item de los enums de pyqt y pyside son más que clases derivadas de int. Es decir, en el fondo son números enteros. Eso significa que podríamos usar un IntEnum, por ejemplo, de la siguiente forma

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from enum import IntEnum

class Enumeration(IntEnum):
   Ok = QMessageBox.Ok
   Cancel = QMessageBox.Cancel
```

Los items del enum resultante se pueden comparar con los items originales y funcionaría perfecto. También son compatibles con PyQt, es decir, se podría hacer algo como esto.

```
box = QMessageBox()
box.addButton(Enumeration.Ok)
box.addButton(Enumeration.Cancel)
```

Debido a que los items de IntEnum son derivados de int.

##### Automatizando

Pero construir un enum de este modo es pesado y no se adapta a los cambios. Esto haría que, por ejemplo, cada vez que en la siguiente versión de qt se agrege un item a `QMessageBox.StandardButtons`, se tenga que agregar también en Enumeration.

Gracias a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13534187/12913664) sabemos que se puede automatizar esto. Qt y sus bindings ofrecen formas de trabajar con algunos enums usando QMetaObject y QEnumMeta. Los que no se pueden trabajar de ese modo, simplemente es iterar sobre el objeto que contiene los valores del enum dejando unicamente los valores que sean instancia del mismisimo enum.

E IntEnum puede ser llamado para crear un enum dinamicamente.

A continuación, un código de muestra:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from enum import IntFlag, IntEnum

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/13534187/12913664
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690064/dynamically-create-an-enum-with-custom-values-in-python

def enum_from_pyqt(parent, name) -> IntEnum:
    enum_cls = getattr(parent, name)

    # Obtenemos el objeto que nos ayudará a trabajar el enum, o None si no existe
    meta = getattr(parent, "staticMetaObject", None)

    if meta is None:
        # Obtenemos un diccionario cuyos valores son instancias del enum
        data = {attr:getattr(enum_cls, attr) for attr in dir(parent) if isinstance(getattr(parent, attr), enum_cls)}
    else:
        # Obtenemos el objeto con los datos del enum
        idx = meta.indexOfEnumerator(enum_cls.__name__)
        enum_meta = meta.enumerator(idx)

        data = {enum_meta.key(i):enum_meta.value(i) for i in range(enum_meta.keyCount())}

    return IntEnum(name, data)


for enum in [enum_from_pyqt(QtWidgets.QMessageBox, "StandardButton"),
             enum_from_pyqt(QtCore.Qt, "AlignmentFlag")]:

    print("enum:", enum)
    print()

    print("values")
    print("------")

    for k in enum:
        print(k.name.ljust(20), k.value)

    print()

print("enum.AlignCenter == QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter", enum.AlignCenter == QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
print("enum.AlignCenter == QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft  ", enum.AlignCenter == QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
```

Que produce:

```
enum: <enum 'StandardButton'>

values
------
NoButton             0
Ok                   1024
Save                 2048
SaveAll              4096
Open                 8192
Yes                  16384
YesToAll             32768
No                   65536
NoToAll              131072
Abort                262144
Retry                524288
Ignore               1048576
Close                2097152
Cancel               4194304
Discard              8388608
Help                 16777216
Apply                33554432
Reset                67108864
RestoreDefaults      134217728
Default              256
Escape               512
FlagMask             768
ButtonMask           -769

enum: <enum 'AlignmentFlag'>

values
------
AlignAbsolute        16
AlignBaseline        256
AlignBottom          64
AlignCenter          132
AlignHCenter         4
AlignHorizontal_Mask 31
AlignJustify         8
AlignLeading         1
AlignRight           2
AlignTop             32
AlignVCenter         128
AlignVertical_Mask   480

enum.AlignCenter == QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter True
enum.AlignCenter == QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft   False
```

##### Nota sobre flags

A diferencia de los enum, no se puede convertir un flag de alguno de los bindings de qt en un IntFlag, ya que estos en realidad resultan no ser compatibles con dichos bindings y no trabajan correctamente el sistema de flags que ya viene incluido en Qt.

Sin embargo, si no se desea esa funcionalidad, se puede convertir en un IntEnum, como vimos en el código de más arriba con `QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag`.